# Error in Copying file of a system app into another location

Tags: java, android

I am developing a **system app** in which I have to copy the xml file belonging to another **system app** onto a known location of my **rooted** phone. 
First I tried to do this in the command prompt , using **adb shell** and the command

```
cp /data/data/owner_app_pkg_name/shared_prefs/file.xml /storage/sdcard0/FOLDERNAME/file2.xml
```

It worked perfectly.

However, when I tried to do the same thing programmatically in **my** system app, using

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /data/data/owner_app_pkg_name/shared_prefs/file.xml /storage/sdcard0/FOLDERNAME/file2.xml");
```

It does not work.

Moreover, if I created a copy of file.xml in the same directory through command prompt of the system and *then* executed the code in **my app** using the *copied* file's name, it works.

Can someone please tell me what I have to do to directly copy the file.xml used by the **owner system app** to the location I want, using the java code of **my** system app as I have mentioned above?

Comment: A "system app" does not run as root, and so can't access private files of other apps with different owners.  Perhaps your root shell copy ended up with world read permissions.  You can do an `ls -l` of the two (from your root shell) to see.

Comment: I will try that. Is it possible to make a system app run as root and bypass this issue?

Comment: No.  Apps do not run as root.  However if you can run as the same uid as the target app you would avoid the problem.

Comment: I found out how to get the target app's UID (using ApplicationInfo().uid) but can I set the uid of **my** app manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem by using the commands

```
adb shell
chmod 666 /data/data/owner_app_pkg_name/shared_prefs/file.xml
```

and then running my app. But how to run chmod command from the java code of my app itself?

Comment: You cannot, as you do not own the file.  If you have an `su` root hack you might be able to invoke `chmod` via that as covered in numerous other questions here, but only `chmod` would potentially run as root,  not your app.

Comment: I think I have exhausted all my options.. at least I could find a work around (though it's painful). Thanks for all your help!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void copyFile() throws IOException {
    InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(new File("/data/data/owner_app_pkg_name/shared_prefs/file.xml"));
    OutputStream outStream= new FileOutputStream(new File("/storage/sdcard0/FOLDERNAME/file2.xml"));

    // Transfer bytes from in to outStream
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = inStream.read(buf)) > 0) {
        outStream.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    inStream.close();
    outStream.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Satheesh, but like Chris, said, I get an exception as follows:                                                  ` java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/data/com.lge.camera/shared_prefs/back_camera.xml: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)`