# Changing the UID of a system app

Tags: java, android

I know that we can get the UID of a system app using **ApplicationInfo().uid()**. But can I **set** the UID of my app to what that function returns?

I need to do this because I am attempting to copy a shared_pref file belonging to a target system app to a location on the sdcard. Btw, my device is **rooted**.

More details on my problem at [Error in Copying file of a system app into another location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20374810/error-in-copying-file-of-a-system-app-into-another-location?noredirect=1#comment30420117_20374810).

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands as root using the "su" program which is installed when rooting. There is no way to do it directly with the Android SDK.

http://www.stealthcopter.com/blog/2010/01/android-requesting-root-access-in-your-app/